# Is it idiomatic to say "don't crumple the mat"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> **[crumple](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/crumple?q=crumple)**[transitive, intransitive] crumple (something) (up) (into something)
>   to press or crush something into folds; to become pressed, etc. into
>   folds
>
> She crumpled the letter up into a ball and threw it on the fire.
>
> This material crumples very easily.

Now you roll out a mat & it looks like this, flat, no rough surface or folds

[image]

Your kid runs around on it & makes it not flat, with some rough surface or folds like this

[image]

Is it idiomatic to say "don't crumple the mat**"**?

Comment: In Britain we might call the undesired action 'rucking' or 'rumpling'  a mat. In fact, 'rumple' would be more natural than 'crumple' where I live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, assuming this is the toddler, remember that they don't speak English.

> Look Isabel, you've messed up the mat. It's all crumpled (or rumpled) (or folded up) (or lumpy etc).  Let's get it flat again.  {demonstrate with toddler how to flatten a mat}. Now be careful next time.

It will probably only take about 50 times of telling her for her to start to get the idea.

This is really a parenting question, since communication with a native speaker isn't occurring.